# How do I keep hidden controls from appearing during page load in Windows XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

My Windows Store app has a XAML page with several invisible controls on it (Opacity = 0).  I have storyboards that fade these in based on user actions.

Even though the opacity of these controls is 0 in the designer, they still appear for about 1 second on the screen while the page loads.  How do I prevent Windows from displaying these controls?

Comment: What type of controls? Tried the Visibility="Collapsed" attribute?

Comment: The controls are StackPanels that contain many other controls. Both Opacity = 0 and Visibility = Collapsed eventually make the controls disappear, but the controls are always visible on page load.

Comment: Did you try to remove your storyboard to see if you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes, I ended up removing the storyboard, which made the problem go away. There seems to be some conflict with the built-in transitions shown when the page is loaded and my storyboard to make the controls visible later on cue.